# pyspark.pandas vs pandas DataFrame pivot (not working in pandas on pyspark api with non numeric columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to do a pivot in pyspark.pandas, that works on regular pandas api but not in pandas on pyspark api. The problem is that the `values` column is not a numeric type

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.pandas as ps

df_dict = {'A':[1,2,3],'B':[1,2,3],'C':['X','Y','Z']}

df_pd = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
df_ps = ps.DataFrame(df_dict)


pivot_pd = df_pd.pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='C')
pivot_ps = df_ps.pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='C')
```

pivot_ps fails. This is the error trace:

```
File "/home/user/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/pandas/frame.py", line 6276, in pivot
    raise TypeError("values should be a numeric type.")
```

Any workarounds?